# Pass command line arg to react-native run-ios through Xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native, environment-variables

I am trying to set up different `.env` files depending on the scheme which is being built through Xcode. I am using [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config).

If I run the following command through terminal, it works as expected

```
ENVFILE=.env.production react-native run-ios
```

However, I am trying to pass the `ENVFILE` via Xcode.

I have added an Argument as shown in the picture, however it does not work.

[image]

This is a React Native project and my config files sit one level above the `ios` directory. This could potentially be the problem. However, modifying the arg to `ENVFILE=../config/.env.production` does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is about how to switch react-native-config environments for iOS and it is answered in docs - https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#ios-1 .

Arguments passed on Launch is different thing and intended to be used only for debug and this arguments apply on *built* binary app.